# Validate Json data while calling DeserializeObject<Object>( ... )

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to validate Json code after I deserialize it.
For example if I have ...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
public Car
{
  public int Year{ get; set; }
  public String Make{ get; set; }
}
...
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(json)
```

I want to validate that the year is `< 2017 && >=1900`, (for example).
Or maybe make sure that the Make is a non empty string, (or it is an acceptable value).

I know I could add a `Validate()` type function *after* I deserialize, but I am curious if there was a way of doing it at the same time as the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(json)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the right tool for the job is a [serialization callback](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm)

Just create a `Validate` method and slap on it an `[OnDeserialized]` attribute:

```
public Car
{
  public int Year{ get; set; }
  public String Make{ get; set; }

  [OnDeserialized]
  internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
  {
    if (Year > 2017 || Year < 1900)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("...or something else");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Plug it in with the Setters.

```
public class Car
{
    private int _year;

    public int Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set
        {
            if (_year > 2017 || _year < 1900)
                throw new Exception("Illegal year");
            _year = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

For entire object validation, just validate anytime a value is set.

```
public class Car
{
    private int _year;
    private string _make;

    public string Make 
    {
        get { return _make; }
        set
        {
            _make = value;
            ValidateIfAllValuesSet();
        }
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set
        {
            _year = value;
            ValidateIfAllValuesSet();
        }
    }

    private void ValidateIfAllValuesSet()
    {
        if (_year == default(int) || _make == default(string))
            return;

        if (_year > 2017 || _year < 1900)
            throw new Exception("Illegal year");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the two values are related, for example, if the `year` range depends on the `make` or something like that. I almost have to wait for all the values to be set.

Comment: Then write a single setter that calls validate if all the data is provided.

Comment: I would rather have either `DataAnnotations` that can be used to validate the car after its fully built, or just a method called `ValidateCar` that can run any logic you need to do after deserialization.  Having your setters run logic can get messy fast.

Comment: I completely agree. It's the simplest solution without getting fancy, but the moment you start to use eventual consistency and eventual validation, it gets ugly. It's much cleaner just to call obj.Validate() after deserialization.